# Is it a security risk to be using Doctrine1 today, as the PHP Library has not been updated in 8 years?

Tags: php

We have an application that is running Doctrine1 and it would be a VERY large undertaking to upgrade from Doctrine1 to the current Doctrine3 (essentially a complete rewrite).

From a security standpoint, what is the risk with using this library?

Comment: Did you do a Google search for what vulnerabilities exist in Doctrine1 and the version of PHP you are using?

Answer (score 4):

Any time you are using a library that has not and cannot be updated, you are increasing your exposure to risks of vulnerabilities in that library (and in **other** libraries *embedded* into that library). This [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5otkkU5meE) by Kymberlee Price does a nice job of talking through some of the impact a third-party library or integration of any kind can have on your codebase's attack surface and risk profile.